# Deploying a python cloud service/webjob to Azure via GIT

Tags: python, git, azure, msbuild

I'm trying to find a way to bind my cloud service or webjob to GIT.
[I've tried following this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso-git/)

Everything worked well - the files were uploaded and a build job was initiated on the server, **BUT** I keep getting the following error:

> C:\a\src\AzureCloudService1\Crawler\Crawler.pyproj (48, 0) The
>   imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Python
>   Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Worker.targets" was not found. Confirm
>   that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
>   file exists on disk.

I've searched this problem and based on suggestions I've found I uploaded the missing files and changed the location that points to them.
The above missing files were then read successfully but they're trying to use other files as well, which can't be found for the same reason. 
Shortly, I get a chain of "not found" files.
I'm out of ideas, will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is little relationship with Azure Could Service deployment, it’s the limitation of VSO building process. The VSO uses MSBuild to check code and build project, and which is lack of python tools dependence on VSO server. Here is [the same issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/128) with you and explained by VSO engineer. I’d like to quote a paragraph of this communication:

> VSO Build preview is going to be able to better support non-.NET projects, and explicit support for Python projects will come eventually but is already available through command-line options. Getting Cloud Service projects changed to work better is more difficult (I don't even have a good contact for that team right now). Our own team also has conflicted priorities, and right now we've got everyone focusing on fixing crashes and issues that affect most of our users - working around Cloud Service's lack of extensibility is one of the (many) things that gets pushed down the list.

Currently, we can publish Cloud Server to Azure directly in Visual Studio as a workaround.
For more details, please read [Python web and worker roles with Python Tools 2.2 for Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-ptvs/)